# flask 400 Bad Request while executing POST method

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a connecting to a existing postgreSQL database and trying to add new values to the table using the post method. So, far my code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
POSTGRES = {
'user': 'postgres',
'pw': 'postgres',
'db': 'In',
'host': 'localhost',
'port': '5432',
 }
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:\
%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
      key = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, primary_key=True)
      place_name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(100))
      admin_name1 = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(100))
      latitude = db.Column(db.NUMERIC(9, 6))
      longitude = db.Column(db.NUMERIC(9, 6))

      def __init(self, key, place_name, admin_name1, latitude, longitude):
            self.key = key
            self.place_name = place_name
            self.admin_name1 = admin_name1
            self.latitude = latitude
            self.longitude = longitude


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('add_location.html')


@app.route('/post_location', methods=['POST'])
def post_location():
    user = User(request.form['key'], request.form['palce_name'], 
    request.form['admin_name1'], request.form['latitude'],
            request.form['longitude'])
    db.session.add(user)
    print user
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```

And this is my add_location.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/post_location">
<label>Pin:</label>
<input type="text" name="key" />
<label>City:</label>
<input type="text" name="place_name" />

<label>Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="admin_name1" />
<label>Lat:</label>
<input type="text" name="latitude" />
<label>Long:</label>
<input type="text" name="longitude" />


<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything seems fine but I am still getting a bad request error. Is it because the datatype of my postgresql table is not matching with the code.

Comment: what url are you accessing?

Comment: i am just using add_location.html form to insert data in postgreSQL table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typo in function `post_location()`,  the word `palce` in `request.form['palce_name']` should be `place`.

Flask treat such issues as client's error, so you got a 400.

Comment: yeah, I mean `palce` --> `place`, not `palce_name` -> `place`

Comment: Now it says request.form['longitude'])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)

Comment: Another typo, `__init` of class **User** should be `__init__`

Comment: So many typos, there should be something which should tell you about your typos.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my issue was that I was trying to `POST` a file in a way that Flask didn't seem to understand. I was doing this:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileEl"/>
```

```js
// Incorrect:
let response = await fetch("http://example.com/upload", {
  method: "POST",
  body: fileEl.files[0],
}).then(r => r.json());
```

When Flask seems to expect files as form data:

```js
// Correct:
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fileEl.files[0]);

let response = await fetch("http://example.com/upload", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
}).then(r => r.json());
```